# How to bind to load completion of new Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager

Tags: wordpress, media, uploader, wordpress-3.5

I need to modify the output of the new Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager after it has loaded all of the items to browse in the library and gallery views but I cannot for the life of me find an event that I can bind to...

Does anybody know if there is something like a 'wpMediaEditorLoaded' event triggered when all the images have been loaded or something similar that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I found I could use this

```
wp.media.view.Attachments.prototype.on('ready',function(){
    //this runs once for each tab in the media editor so unbind previous versions
        jQuery(document).unbind('ajaxComplete', mediaLibraryLoaded);
        jQuery(document).bind('ajaxComplete', mediaLibraryLoaded);
      });
var mediaLibraryLoaded = function(e, xhr, options) {        
         jQuery(document).unbind('ajaxComplete', mediaLibraryLoaded);
        //do stuff here
       }
```